# Trouble Connecting Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio to Amazon RDS

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, rds

I have been trying to create a new instance of SQL Server using Amazon RDS. Initially I can connect my SQL Server Management Studio to the instance but if I attempt to login in again I keep getting the error below. Is there something wrong with my settings that prevents connecting a second time?

### TITLE: Connect to Server

Cannot connect to [Server End Point from AWS].

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 53)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=53&LinkId=20476

---

The network path was not found

---

BUTTONS:

### OK

Comment: Try looking at this stackoverflow document: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060667/why-am-i-getting-cannot-connect-to-server-a-network-related-or-instance-speci